# declare an associative array for use in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to use the following for loop to create a bunch of null values initially (however these will be updated).
I want the array to end up looking like this:

```
this.add[
{
    name: null;
    number: null;
},
{
    ... etc
}]
```

so I want to use this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    this.add[i]["name"] = null;
    this.add[i]["number"] = null;
}
```

but I am not sure how to declare "add" to ensure I am able to declare this.
I have tried to use the following:

```
this.add = {};
```

however this gives me the error:

> cannot set property 'name' of defined

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

```
this.add = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    this.add[i] = {name: null, number: null};
}
```